# Unifying record type

Tags: purescript

As a learning exercise, I'm trying to define a newtype to serve as a holder of functions that can convert `Show`-able values to `Eff`ects, i.e.:

```
newtype ShEff a = ShEff (forall eff. Show a => a -> Eff eff Unit)
```

However, this:

```
f :: forall a. ShEff a
f = ShEff logShow
```

fails to compile with this error:

```
  Could not match type

    ( console :: CONSOLE
    | t2
    )

  with type

    eff1


while trying to match type Eff
                             ( console :: CONSOLE
                             | t2
                             )
  with type Eff eff1
while checking that expression logShow
  has type t0 -> Eff eff1 Unit
in value declaration f
```

Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `logShow` is

```
forall eff. Show a => a -> Eff (console :: CONSOLE | eff) Unit
```

so you can't store it inside `ShEff`, since that must work for *every* `eff`, and `logShow` only works for rows containing the `CONSOLE` effect.

You have two options:

1. Move the `eff` type argument outside `ShEff`:

   ```
   newtype ShEff eff a = ShEff (a -> Eff eff Unit)

   f :: forall a eff. Show a => ShEff (console :: CONSOLE | eff) a
   f = ShEff logShow
   ```
2. Add the constraint inside `ShEff`:

   ```
   newtype ShEff a = ShEff (forall eff. a -> Eff (console :: CONSOLE | eff) Unit)

   f :: forall a eff. Show a => ShEff a
   f = ShEff logShow
   ```

Also notice that I've moved the `Show a` constraint outside `ShEff` in both cases.